# Parquet Drill end of line

Tags: apache-drill

I have conveted a text file on a parquet file using Drill on a Windows env. It worked fine but when I read the parquet files on a linux env using RStudio the last column show the windows end of line(\r). How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and used REGEXP:

`` SELECT
    CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(`mycolumn`, '\R', '') AS VARCHAR) AS `mycolumn`
    etc ``

Which solved the issue.